# segment:offset in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

When you define a variable in assembly, you can only output it by using the segment:offset operand. You get the offset value by the keyword offset itself. But why for my code below, I still get the right output even though I didn't use the offset directive. But if my variable is a string and I used the output string in dos which is mov ax,9h then int21h, I get the correct output using the mov dx, offset msg then the dos interrupt to output string.

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data
msg1 db 50d         ;2 in ascii table
msg2 db 51d         ;3 in ascii table
msg3 db 52d         ;4 in ascii table

.code

main proc
mov ax, @data       ;point to the data segment
mov ds, ax

mov dl, msg1        ;why does this work, it was suppose to be ds:offset msg1
mov ah, 2h          ;output character
int 21h  

mov dl, msg2        ;why does this work, it was suppose to be ds:offset msg1
mov ah, 2h          ;output character
int 21h

mov dl, msg3        ;why does this work, it was suppose to be ds:offset msg1
mov ah, 2h          ;output character
int 21h 


mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

main endp
end main
```

---

I just need to know what the int21h needs. I thought that if you put something in the variable, you always need the segment and offset. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Int 21h/ah=2` prints out a single character. The character goes into _DL_. Offset isn't what you want for a single character. `mov dl, msg1` is the same as `mov dl, [msg1]` in _MASM/TASM_. If you use `int 21h/ah=9` which writes a string out then the offset needs to be passed in _DX_ (and you'd need offset to get the address of the label)

Comment: Addresses in x86 assembly have a segment and offset part. A statement like `msg1 db 50d` assigns an address to the symbol `msg1`. This address has a segment and offset part. When the OFFSET operator is applied to a symbol like `msg1` that's an address (eg `OFFSET msg1`) it evaluates to just the offset part of the address. When the symbol is used alone, just `msg1`, it evaluates to the full address with both the segment and offset parts. Since you've used the `.model small` directive, the assembler assumes DS points to the data segment, and so it assumes that segment part of  `msg1` is in DS.

Comment: So basically, when you want to output a char that is in the variable, you can just directly put the variable in the register? Then for string (stored in the variable also), you need both the segment and the offset value for the ds and dx respectively?

Comment: So the reason why you can't put the variable which contain a string in a register is because when you want to output it using the dos, it requires both the segment and offset value from ds and dx respectively, am I correct?

Comment: What you need is determined by the function of `int 21h` you use. The function number is in `AH`. Take a look at Ralf Brown's Interrupt List: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm. You use `Int 21/AH=02h ` which needs a character in `DL`. However, function 09h needs a SEG:OFS address in DS:DX.

Comment: Okay, so I just need to know what the int21h needs. I thought that if you put something in the variable, you always need the segment and offset. Thanks to all of you!